# Get the User ID Who Owns a Given Blog ID in Multisite

Tags: multisite, users, user-roles, blog-id

I am working on creating a function that will take a `$blog_id` and return the corresponding `$user_id` of the user who owns/created the blog in a multi site network.

```
public function SelectOwnerUserIdFromBlogId( $blog_id ) { ... }
```

I have been reviewing the database and the closest thing I can find is looking at the wp_usermeta table and filtering on capabilities but this feels too hackish. Any better idea?

```
SELECT user_id as UserId,
    IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', 2), '_', -1) = 'capabilities', 1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_key, '_', 2), '_', -1)) as BlogId
FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE meta_key like '%_capabilities'
    AND meta_value like '%administrator%'
```

[image: Query results.]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but this is the best way. Might help people coming here in the future.

`$get_users = get_users( array( 'blog_id' => get_current_blog_id() ) );
$user_id = $get_users[0]->ID;`

Comment: why would you name an array variable that looks like a function?